# Nested Error Handling in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I am trying to run an error handler in an error handler in Excel VBA, but the second error handler never runs. It just gives me an error message. This is my code.

```
Sub func()
   On Error GoTo error1 
   'code
   Exit Sub

error1:
   On Error GoTo error2
   'code
   Resume Next

error2:
   'code
   Resume Next
```

Basically, the function can run into 2 possible errors. I try to run the code and if it runs into an error, it tries to fix error1, and if that fails then error2 will fix it. The debug works for error1, but if error2 is the problem, the code will just fail.

Comment: I think it's because you haven't dealt with the first error yet and I'm not sure that `On Error` will work correctly outside of the main body of the procedure.  But, saying that - add `On Error GoTo -1` after  your `Error1:` label and it looks like it then goes on to `Error2`.  In my test I put `Debug.Print 1/0` in your first error trap and it jumped to `Error2`, then back due to the `Resume Next` and then ran through `Error2` again because that's how the flow of the code works...

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yuck! As soon as you're adding that into your code, I think you are in trouble!

Comment: @Rory  Yep, can't disagree with that.  Only found out about setting it to -1 a couple of months ago but can't see a reason for using it.  I prefer trying to stop the code from jumping to an error routine in the first place - only if it's an error that I didn't account for.

Comment: i tried that and it ran error2 four times

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how to handle 2 potential errors

Answer (score 0):

This is how to throw two specific errors, based on a password char:

```
Sub Bar()

    Dim password As String

    On Error GoTo err1

    password = "asd^"

    If InStr(1, password, "&") Then Err.Raise 9990, Description:="No &!"
    If InStr(1, password, "^") Then Err.Raise 9991, Description:="No ^!"

    Exit Sub
err1:

Select Case Err.Number
    Case 9990:
        Debug.Print Err.Description
    Case 9991:
        Debug.Print Err.Description & ":("
End Select

End Sub
```

---

This is a possible way to do it using `-1`, as mentioned by @Darren Bartup-Cook in the comments. However, it is **strongly not advisable**, unless you do not want to write bad code for a reason of your own:

```
Sub Bar()

    On Error GoTo err1
    Debug.Print 0 / 0
    Exit Sub

err1:

    Debug.Print "err1"
    On Error GoTo -1
    On Error GoTo err2

    Debug.Print 5 / 0
    Debug.Print "Just testing..."

err2:
    Debug.Print "err2"

End Sub
```

There are plenty of better ways to do it, if you want to catch 2 errors, try the following:

```
Sub Bar()

    On Error GoTo err1

    Debug.Print 4 / 0

    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub

err1:
    Select Case Err.Number

    Case 6:
        Debug.Print "Overflow!"
    Case 11:
        Debug.Print "Division by 0 error!"
    Case Else:
        Debug.Print "Another error!"
    End Select

End Sub
```

It catches `Div/0` and `Overflow` and gives you info about them in the immediate window.

Comment: im trying to catch user input errors. For example, if user needs to create a password that does not include & or ^, then I want to create an error handler if pw contains & and another one for if pw contains ^. I know in this example you can search string instead of doing error handling, but I want a to provide a solution through error handling if possible